What is so special about JUICE's flyby with Earth and Moon?
In a recent article about the JUICE mission and it's planned flyby on Earth and Moon
the Austrian news website orf.at writes:

Nach Angaben der Europäische Weltraumorganisation (ESA) ist der Vorbeiflug um
Mond und Erde eine „riskante“ Premiere.
Die ESA bezeichnete das Manöver als riskante Herausforderung, die noch
keine andere Weltraummission im Plan hatte.

Translated by DeepL.com:

According to the European Space Agency (ESA), the flyby around the moon
and Earth is a "risky" first.
The ESA described the maneuver as a risky challenge that no other
space mission had ever planned.

Emphasis in both quotes mine.
Of course any maneuver in space is somewhat risky but swing by maneuvers have
been executed countless times. What is it that makes this maneuver so special
that no other mission has ever done it?

JUICE probe will be 1st to use gravity of Earth and moon to slingshot to Jupiter
In short this 'double gravity assist' to propel JUICE towards Jupiter, has not been done before, so that is why it is a first.
TL;DR:
Unfortunately the article you link skirts the basic details, but a quick google results in:


JUICE ...on a mission to make detailed observations of the giant gas planet and its three large, ocean-bearing moons – Ganymede, Callisto and Europa.
Why does it take so long to get to Jupiter? Well, the short answer is that its less to do with the distance between Earth and Jupiter and more to do with fighting the Sun’s massive gravitational pull as you venture outwards through the Solar System.
...they make use of ‘gravity-assist’ (or ‘flyby’) manoeuvres to gain energy by swinging through the strong gravitational fields of various planets on the way.


Shooting for the Moon
Juice’s first boost will come from its home planet, when it returns to Earth in August 2024, more than one year after launch.
In fact, in a first-of-its-kind flyby, Juice will first pass by the Moon to give it an extra kick and make the flyby of Earth that takes place 1.5 days later even more effective.
But even with this extra boost, to get the most out of the gravity assist, Juice has to arrive at the Earth-Moon system at precisely the correct time, at the correct speed and travelling in the correct direction.
That’s where today’s (2023) manoeuvre comes in.
On 17 November, at 16:10 (CET) (2023), Juice’s main engine performed a burn that lasted roughly 43 minutes.
“This manoeuvre used up roughly 363 kg of fuel – or almost exactly 10% of the 3650 kg of fuel that Juice launched with,” says Julia Schwartz, Flight Dynamics Engineer at ESA’s ESOC mission control centre in Germany.
“It was the first part of a two-part manoeuvre to put Juice on the correct trajectory for next summer’s encounter with Earth and the Moon. This first burn did 95% of the work, changing Juice’s velocity by almost 200 m/s,” adds Julia.
“Juice is one of the heaviest interplanetary spacecraft ever launched, with a total mass of around 6000 kg, so it took a lot of force and a lot of fuel to achieve this.”

https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Operations/Juice_burns_hard_towards_first-ever_lunar-Earth_flyby


This burn is one of two necessary to put JUICE on the right trajectory for the Earth-moon gravity assist, the first in the series of assists, which will occur in Aug. 2024.
"This first burn did 95% of the work, changing JUICE’s velocity by almost 200 meters per second [656 feet per second]," said Schwartz. "JUICE is one of the heaviest interplanetary spacecraft ever launched, with a total mass of around 6,000 kilograms [13,228 pounds], so it took a lot of force and a lot of fuel to achieve this."

https://www.space.com/esa-juice-spacecraft-executes-major-maneuver


"A lunar-Earth flyby has never been attempted before," says Angela Dietz. "There are risks, but all of Juice's onboard systems have been rigorously tested, and we are well prepared." She added, "Due to the low altitudes, large velocity changes and strict navigation requirements involved, the flight control team needs to be ready to react at a moment's notice."

https://www.spacedaily.com/reports/Juice_Prepares_for_Historic_Double_Flyby_of_Moon_and_Earth_999.html

https://universemagazine.com/en/take-a-shortcut-to-venus-juice-prepares-for-a-historic-double-flyby-of-the-moon-and-earth/

Just for comparison, the Voyager probes were 721.9kg and Galileo 2560kg.

Lots of interesting information here, but none of it really answers the question. Gravity assists always require a well-aimed incoming trajectory. Presumably the double assist requires more precision, that's not surprising, but it's a big difference if it needs to be like 20% more precise or rather two orders of magnitude more precise. I'd also find it interesting how much more Δv the moon flyby actually gives.

I of course like your answers in general, but I have to agree with leftaroundabout, A single sentence can state "it also uses the Moon" rather than a foot and a half of copy/pasted general information. I also have a hunch that in addition to "it also uses the Moon", answers  to "What is so special..." will include some orbital mechanics, mission planning, and attention to corrections for subsequent flybys if the first one isn't precise. I don't think this is currently a good answer, should be so up-voted, or be the accepted answer... yet.  -1 for now...

@uhoh good explanation of the issues here. I thought of mostly the same stuff. I'm not sure I'll downvote, but I'm not upvoting either. I'll leave it as-is for the moment.
